# Customizing inline foreign key with no repetition

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i have these models:

## models.py

```
class Offer(BaseModel):
    code =  models.CharField(_("Codice Offerta"), max_length=16, blank=False, null=False, default=0, editable=False)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, verbose_name=_('Azienda'), related_name='company')
    outcome = models.CharField(_('Esito Offerta'), choices=OUTCOME, max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.CharField(_("Inserita da"), max_length=64, blank=False, null=True)

class Product(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(_("Nome Prodotto"),max_length=1024, blank = False, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(_("Categoria"),max_length=1024, blank = False, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)

class ProductOfferDoc(BaseModel):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=False,null=False, choices=DOC)
    number = models.IntegerField(_('Num.'), default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(_('Prezzo'),max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,default=0.00,blank=True, null=True )
    offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer, related_name='related_doc')

admin.py
class DocAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    extra = 1
    model = ProductOfferDoc

class OfferAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Offer
    list_display = ['code','company']
    inlines = [
        DocAdmin,
        CourseAdmin,
        RiskAdmin,
        ServiceAdmin,
        SanitaryAdmin,
    ]
```

When I create an offer, I can add as many `ProductOfferDoc` as I want because this is a foreign key, but I don't want to allow to insert the same `ProductOfferDoc` multiple times. Where can I make these controls over the form?

Comment: You can add a `unique=True` parameter on the `ProductOfferDoc.offer` foreign key, but it seems your architecture is wrong — if a `Product` can have only one `ProductOfferDoc`, why not just invert the relation, and add a `Product.doc = models.ForeignKey(ProductOfferDoc)` field instead?

Comment: @Ianizz i need to save more ProductOfferDoc, but when i write the form, i can't repeat the same ProductOfferDoc instance..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`models.OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField):

```
class ProductOfferDoc(BaseModel):
    # ...
    offer = models.OneToOneField(Offer, related_name='related_doc')
```